# How do I speed up my Offscreen OpenGL pointcloud warp rendering code?

Tags: c++, opengl, transformation

I'm working on a visual odometry algorithm that tracks movement of the camera between images. An integral part of this algorithm is being able to generate incremental dense warped images of a reference image, where each pixel has a corresponding depth (so it can be considered a point cloud of width x height dimensions)

I haven't had much experience working with OpenGL in the past, but having gone through a few tutorials, I managed to setup an offscreen rendering pipeline to take in a transformation matrix and render the pointcloud from the new perspective. I'm using VBOs to load the data in the GPU and renderbuffers to render, and glReadPixels() to read into CPU memory.

On my Nvidia card, I can render at ~1 ms per warp. Is that the fastest I can render the data (640x480 3D points)? This step is proving to be a major bottleneck for my algorithm, so I'd really appreciate any performance tips!

(I thought that one optimization could be rendering only in grayscale, since I don't really care about colour, but it seems like internally OpenGL uses colour anyway)

My current implementation is at 
https://gist.github.com/icoderaven/1212c7623881d8cd5e1f1e0acb7644fb,
and the shaders at
https://gist.github.com/icoderaven/053c9a6d674c86bde8f7246a48e5c033

Thanks!

Comment: could it be that it's not the rendering but the copying of the framebuffer which is costing you most? Maybe you could create a pool of framebuffers so you can continue rendering while copying already completed ones?

Comment: The problem is that since my algorithm is sequential on the warps, I have to wait on the output of the warped image before I obtain a new transform to use. I do understand that the CPU-GPU memcpy takes time, but I feel that should be faster than the time taken. Also, I tried this out on a Jetson TX1, in which the GPU and CPU share memory, and there it was taking ~3ms so I'd like to think that there's something else that impacting the run time.
Also, I tried a first pass profiling step, but all the symbols seemed like GL driver calls, and I'm not too proficient at parsing that.

Comment: I can see that you're allocating and deallocating memory for each frame. I wouldn't be surprised if this is a big part of your overhead. I'd suggest to try to profile it without copying the pixels and then without allocation and deallocation. Mabe the `display` method can receive a pointer to a reusable buffer?
Is the following part of your algorithm highly-parallelizable? Maybe converting it to a GPU implementation would be beneficial as you could avoid unnecessary movement of the data?

Comment: @patrik-h Ok, so if I don't `glReadPixels()`, it is super fast (7 us), but that defeats the point. Allocating the image buffer before calling the `display` method didn't affect the timing performance. 

I'd really like to not move everything to the GPU because of other complications in my algorithm downstream (and the fact that I want to eventually be able to run everything on the CPU). I was hoping that using something like a Jetson would help me avoid memcpy overheads. Are there any specific compilation flags that I should be specifying apart from -o3 and -march

Comment: well, now you know that the copy operation is what you need to optimize. Have you tried creating a GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER instead of a GL_FRAMEBUFFER? As you're only interested in a single channel, have you tried just copying a single channel over (ie using GL_RED for example)? Have you tried copying floats instead of bytes (more data to transfer but less processing?)

Comment: Hm, I don't quite understand how I'd create a GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER if I need to render every time I call `display`. Do I create a separate write framebuffer, then blit to read framebuffer, then read?
Also, I tried using floats instead of uchars and GL_RED, and it gave me a marginal speedup (~2.9 ms instead of ~3.4 ms)

Comment: hmm...yeah, GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER probably doesn't help you here as you'd need to blit from a from one to another which has its own cost. It could be that what you're seeing is essentially the latency to transfer memory from host to client, you'd probably similar performance even with higher resolutions. The only ways I can think of to hide latency would be to pack more data into a transfer but as you need sequential processing, I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: What NVIDIA card are we talking here? The public NvAPI includes the ability to warp the framebuffer on Maxwell / Pascal GPUs. I was pretty surprised it wasn't guarded by the NDA version, but you do have to deal with some very lackluster documentation.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I have a Titan, and a TX1, which are Kepler and Maxwell architectures respectively. I didn't quite follow the comment on the NDA version. Also, by warp I meant image warp (so an operation $w(x;\theta)$ where x is a pixel and $\theta$ are parameters of the warp (here a SE3 transform), and not the CUDA warp, but I'll be curious to know if there are specific optimizations I could get by using kernels.